# UPS with pure sine wave

Tags: ups

I'm looking for a UPS that produces a pure sine wave at the output because my PSU has active Power Factor Compensation and from what I read, it doesn't work with pseudo-sine wave output.

So, my system will draw a maximum of 430W with full load. I want just enough time to hibernate the system before it runs out of power. The UPS I'm looking for needs to be:

- atleast 700 VA;
- pure sine output;
- under 150 €;
- quality.

Comment: I don't know if a true sine wave output UPS is actually needed because of Active PFC, but I *really* don't think that all four criteria you listed can be met. You can probably find something that meets the three criteria except for the price, though, but I really doubt you will be able to find *any* true sine wave output UPS in your desired price range, and I can't imagine that you will find any true sine wave output UPS with that kind of power capability in your desired price range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00429N19W)

This seems to be what you are looking for.  It is pure sine wave output, a modest price of $140, 1000 VA, and it is highly rated. It can't be internationally shipped from US Amazon, but this matches your criteria.